# What does ms() in a CSS margin property mean?

Tags: css

I saw this CSS code, but not sure what `ms(2)` means. Any ideas? Thanks.

```
 address {
   margin: 0 0 ms(2);
 }
```

Comment: Does the stylesheet go through a CSS preprocessor, like Sass? https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/function

Comment: Sass Modular Scale?